# How to iterate over repeating values in DataFrame column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a problem of iterating over repeating values. The thing is that grouping is not an option here, due that the column which I should analyse is a string and this will be simply ambiguous.

Let me illustrate an example:

| code | lenght | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111ab | 'len1' | '800 mm' |
| 111ab | 'len2' | '31,0 in' |
| 222cd | 'len1' | '1.500 mm' |
| 222cd | 'len2' | '59,0 in |

The reason why I want to do that is that I want to compare those values over one code. Considering `length` column is a string, I want to somehow create an additional binary column which is having 0 when '800 mm' is written for the len1 and '31.0 in' for len2. Parsing string and re-calculating value is not an option here because some of the values for mm or for in are considered to be rounded or assumed in a certain way. Which means that I want to check if 800 mm for the same code have 31 in and 1500 mm have 59 in.

Long story short: I want to check if 800 mm is 31 in for each code. Just as an example.

How can I properly do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: what you want is really unclear, please provide a DataFrame constructor as input to avoid ambiguity, add an example of values to explain your "*some of the values for mm or for in are considered to be rounded or assumed in a certain way*", also provide the expected output.

Comment: @mozway I want to check wheter 800 mm is always a 31 in for each code

Comment: Do you always have 2 values per group?

Comment: @mozway yes, there are always 2 values

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood the constraints but check the suggestion below. If this doesn't work for you, please be more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your constraints, you seem to want to match an exact pair of values.

What about using `set` operations?

```
df['flag'] = (df.groupby('code')['value']
                .transform(lambda x: 0 if set(x) == set(['800 mm', '31,0 in'])
                                     else np.nan)
             )
```

Or, with a dictionary:

```
mapper = {frozenset(['800 mm', '31,0 in']): 0}

df['flag'] = (df.groupby('code')['value']
                .transform(lambda x: mapper.get(frozenset(x)))
             )
```

Output:

```
    code lenght     value  flag
0  111ab   len1    800 mm   0.0
1  111ab   len2   31,0 in   0.0
2  222cd   len1  1.500 mm   NaN
3  222cd   len2   59,0 in   NaN
```

Comment: That looks cool, thank you. But what if I want to check multiple values between one another? I mean like 2 (800 , 31 and 1500, 59)?

Comment: Have you checked the dictionary approach? You can define as many mappings as you like.

Comment: Not yet, just saw it

Comment: Try for example `mapper = {frozenset(['800 mm', '31,0 in']): 0, frozenset(['1.500 mm', '59,0 in']): 42}`

Comment: thing with frozenset worked. Thank you very much!